# Setting Up to Solve the Diffusion Equation with Nonlinear Neumann

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am really new to Mathematica, so please bear with me if I ask any relatively easy questions. I am trying to model/solve a specific instance of a 1D diffusion equation in which I have a nonlinear Neumann boundary condition at x=1 (length of unit 1). My equations that I have are:

D[u[x,t],t] == D[u[x,t], x, x] for the general diffusion equation;

D[u[1,t],x] == 10 - Log[u[1, t]] for a flux at boundary x=1 that begins at 10 and decreases as a function of Log of concentration at the boundary;

D[u[0,t],x] == 0 for a no flux boundary at x=0;

u[x,0] == 0 for an initial concentration of 0 everywhere in the rod.

What I am trying to see occur is a function where the heat spreads across the rod and smoothes out across the rod to a steady-state/equilibrium; additionally, the goal is to have the flux approach zero and remain at zero (which represents the difference in chemical potentials between the domain and an external source approaching zero).

I have tried to use DSolve to find a symbolic solution for the boundaries and equations, but it returns "General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Trying to build a special solution" as expected.

I wanted it to be more manipulative (with x=L as a boundary instead of x=1 and other coefficients), but a friend recommended using NDSolve. This has been even more confusing and has lead to more errors and useless material.

Am I going about this problem the correct way in which functions I am using? What do you guys recommend that I do instead? If you would like more detail, please let me know! I need all the help I can get.[image]

Comment: `What do you guys recommend that I do instead?` try `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please include your code in Mathematica format, not an image. so that readers can run your code without retyping it.